# My Imageview is not showing in iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

a few moments ago I started to work my project on iPad, so Im having a big trouble because an Imageview that shows perfectly on iPhone does not appear on iPad, this is happening when I compile in the iPad because in the storyboard the imageview is there, Im setting the image by the storyboard but now with this problem I also added to the code, the imageview displays the logo so never changes of image or anything, only of position:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        self.iconImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.nameTexfield.delegate = self;
        BOOL(isiphone5) = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568;
        if(isiphone5){
            self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(130, 254, 60, 60);
            self.pocketImage.frame = CGRectMake(95, 212, 185, 88);
            self.tasksImage.frame = CGRectMake(40, 266, 240, 114);
        }else if ( [(NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"] ) {
            self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(452, 324, 120, 120);
            self.pocketImage.frame = CGRectMake(420, 100, 185, 88);
            self.tasksImage.frame = CGRectMake(392, 150, 240, 114);
       }else{
            self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(130, 210, 60, 60);
            self.pocketImage.frame = CGRectMake(95, 167, 185, 88);
            self.tasksImage.frame = CGRectMake(40, 215, 240, 114);
        }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.50 delay:1.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            if(isiphone5){
                self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(27, 226, 60, 60);

            }else if ( [(NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"] ) {
                self.iconImageView.frame =CGRectMake(452, 195, 120, 120);


            }else{
                self.iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(27, 181, 60, 60);
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

}
```

As you can see I have other image views, the issue is whit the `iconImageView` so I need someones help, I really dont know whats happening.... thanks!

Comment: What is the superview frame? Why aren't you setting relative position or using auto-layout?

Comment: MMM that was the problem! I had autolayout activated, I normally dont use autolayout, thanks I didnt catch that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stay clear of explicitly setting the frames of your views, it is hard to maintain and will cause you problems in the future.

You should either ensure that auto-layout is turned off, set the frames of all views *relative to each other* and then set the auto-resizing rules to specify how they handle different phone / pad screen sizes.

Or you should turn on auto-layout, not set and frames and add constraints to specify the size and position of each view.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it! I had AutoLayout activated because when I activate it the programming frames does not work!